# How to superscript and subscript parameters that are usually inside "": ggplot2 and gt tables

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I am trying to make a table using `library(gt)`. How would I make a column label include superscript or subscript? I have tried using `expression` and square brackets [] or _ etc, but it isn't doing the desired output. I would like a column name of "[H2O] (mg/mL)". Where the 2 is subscript or superscript.

```
data_table <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Petal.Width), SD = sd(Petal.Width), n = n())  %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()

data_table %>% cols_label(
    Mean = expression('[H'[2]'O] (mg/ml)')
  )
```

Similarly, when using ggplot, when trying to make the legend using:

```
labs(colour = "[H2O] (mg/ml)")
```

I would like the 2 to be subscript. I have tried bquote and expression here too and does not work due to the colour assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gt::html` and a `<sub>` tag (or `<sup>` for superscripts) you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

data_table <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Petal.Width), SD = sd(Petal.Width), n = n())  %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()

data_table %>% 
  cols_label(
    Mean = html('H<sub>2</sub>O (mg/ml)')
  )
```

For more information see the [examples](https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html#the-column-labels) in the gt Intro vignette.

[image]

Comment: Works great! When I tried this in the ggplot, it prints out the <sub> </sub> rather than making it superscript. Do you have any ideas or should I ask this in  a separate question?

Comment: `gt` and `ggplot2` are different things. For ggplot2 you have to stick with expression or ... or use the `ggtext` package which allows for styling via HTML.

Comment: .. just had a look. Try with `+ labs(color = bquote(~H[2]*O (mg/ml)))` for ggplot2.